# Disable/Modify Low Battery Warning Windows CE 6

Tags: registry, windows-ce

I want to disable (or at least lower the % amount) the Low Battery Warning from the Windows CE 6 System as i handle the low battery indication in my own application.

I haven't found settings doing this in the Control Panel nor have i found a Registry Hack to lower the battery percentage when the warning is displayed, or completely disable it.

The device is a Denso BHT-1200Q

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this modifications registry:
[How to disable Low Battery message](http://hsm.force.com/publickb/articles/HSM_Article/How-to-disable-Low-Battery-message-on-Dolphin)
 [Windows mobile disable low battery warning](http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/03/05/windows-mobile-disable-low-battery-warning/)
 [Battery driver registry settings](http://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/battery-driver-registry-settings) .

For my device navigator Lexand SM-527 this registry modifications does not work.
If you know another solution, please describe it.

Regedit for wince 6.0:
  [simple little registry editor](http://geekswithblogs.net/BruceEitman/archive/2009/07/27/window-ce-simple-little-registry-editor.aspx) (simple editor).
  Or standard regedit with export and import:
  [rar archive with regedit binary](http://4pda.ru/forum/dl/post/227839/SDHC_16GB_for_WinCE50.rar) (required registration on 4pda).

Comment: Thx for your reply, I'll try this as soon as I get my hands on another mobile device and report back.